# How can I set up my own VPN service that looks like in another country?

Tags: vpn, proxy

When I set up my own VPN service, all the obstacles in the country are still valid, how I can show my own VPN service as if I was in another country.

Can I enable VPN to appear in a different country using a proxy or with a different method with VPN?

Comment: shortly said, you need a server located in a specific location that this will work, that's why I use cheap VPS for 2 eur and setup a vpn on it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most sites that care about where their visitors are located will use IP (address) based geolocation. The IP addresses of the server you are using as a  gateway need to geolocate to the country that you want to appear to be in. This normally requires that you use a server based in that country.

Note that, IP based geolocation is not a science, (it is snake oil and anyone who tries to tell you differently is a charlatan) it's just a bunch of databases that are as accurate as the data provided. The data can and does change randomly and is frequently inaccurate (IPv4 and IPv6 addresses on the same server can be in wildly different locations).

Unfortunately, IP based geolocation is the best snake oil we have.